# Ubuntu создание почтового ящика для сайта

Tags: ubuntu, email, sendmail

Есть VPS с **Ubuntu 12.04** на нем лежит сайт (apache). Для работы с почтой использую sendmail.

**Задача:** создать почтовый ящик для домена на который можно принимать письма.

например: admin@site.com

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Первый же ответ на запрос в гугле "настройка sendmail ubuntu 12.04" - [Ubuntu Server Linux базовая установка и настройка Sendmail](http://prof-labs.ru/blog/nix/80)

Comment: Вот вы ответили написав "а вот там почитай, я погуглил". На данный момент меня интересует этот же вопрос, но ваша ссылка битая.